# PHP custom SQL class, pass output data to another function via array

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got the following situation:

```
$do = mysql_query($sql); 
return array("data"=>array(mysql_fetch_object($do)), "rows"=>mysql_affected_rows());
```

Which is called from another function.  I'm sure you'll see what i'm trying to do, my brain is just too fried right now to figure this out with out sleeping for at least 8 hours soon.

From the "another function" I call the above query via another function, I'd like all the rows to pass over into that array so from this "another function" I can foreach the data out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not getting all of the output is because you are calling `mysql_fetch_object`. This, like other fetch functions, only returns the next row in the pointer (or false). You would either need to perform a while loop on that function, concatinating each loop into your return array, or use someting else (like PDO).

Also, I'd suggest you use PDO::MySQL instead....it is far more powerful than this old mysql plugin. It kills me how often I still see people using this (unless they are on PHP4...but even then...). Additionally, it would solve your problem with one function call to `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`

Anyway...good luck.

Comment: Im not sure about performance, but it is way more secure. Its way easier to do prepared statements using PDO. Its overall way better than the standard mysql_ functions

Comment: Honestly, the performance is so similar that, unless you are looking at millions of concurrent connections, you don't need to care. PDO, on the other hand, is more portable. If you've structured your queries correctly, all that would need to change between using POD::MySQL and PDO::MSSQL is the DSN.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure I understood you right, but from what I think I did, you simply need to something like this.

function foo()
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bad_words`"; 
   $foo = $this->bar($sql);
   print_r($foo);
}

function bar($sql)
{
   $do = mysql_query($sql);
   $return = array(
     "data" => mysql_fetch_object($do),
     "rows" => mysql_fetch_object($do)
);
   //return array("data"=>array(mysql_fetch_object($do)), "rows"=>mysql_affected_rows());
   return $return;
}

Comment: What you did above is exactly how mine looks.  It didn't work like that either, when you print_r, you only get the first row.